# Running GPU to compute without Deep Learning Framework

Tags: python, numba, conv-neural-network

I am writing Convolutional Neural Network without using frameworks like Tensorflow or Pytorch.

I use Windows 10, with Anaconda.

Right now, I have functions such as

```
def normalization(input_data):

def forward_convolutional_layer(input_data, filter_value, num_padding, stride):

def pooling_layer(input_data, pooling_size, stride):
```

Right now, it certainly looks that all the computations are being done via CPU. I want these functions to process their calculations using GPU, which I believe is big strength of Deep Learning.

In order to do so, I know that numba needs to be used, however I am not sure how to use it.

What should I do next?

Answer (score 0):

Read about Numba's CUDA compatibility https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/cuda/index.html
However using Numba on GPU proved a daunting task to me. Maybe CuPy will be more suited to your needs... https://cupy.chainer.org/
CuPy is a library that performs computations on CUDA but at the same time retains syntax and compatibility of NumPy